# ¿Como crear una tabla con columnas de otras tablas en power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Estoy intentando crear una nueva tabla, en la cual pueda introducir informacion de otras tablas ya cargadas en Power Bi.
Hasta el momento, intente con "SUMARIZE", "CROSSJOIN", pero no lo eh logrado.

Lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente:

**FECHA**  **NOMBRE** **VALOR 1** **VALOR 2**

Donde Fecha y Nombre son exactamente en ambas tablas, por lo que puedo introducirlo desde cualquiera de las dos, pero VALOR 1 pertenece a la tabla A  y VALOR 2 pertenece a la TABLA B.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llego tarde a darte una respuesta. No entiendo el objetivo de tener esta tabla, lo lógico es construirla en Power Query y cargarla.
Por otro lado, si realmente lo necesitas en DAX, puedes recurrir por ejemplo a la [función](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`.

```
Tabla = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Tabla1[Fecha],
    Tabla1[Nombre],
    "Valor 1",
    SUM(Tabla1[Valor1]),
    "Valor 2",
    SUM(Tabla2[Valor2])
)
```

Para poder hacer esta tabla es necesario que Tabla1 y Tabla2 tengan algún tipo de relación, bien directa o bien mediante dimensiones.